# X-ticks do not match defined bins in plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn's FacetGrid to plot multiple matplotlib.pyplot.hist plots with predefined bins. I want it to show the X-tick labels.

Based on what I read, I was trying:

```
bins = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,40,50,60,80]
g = sns.FacetGrid(allData, col="Survived", row="Sex")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "Age", bins=bins)
g.set_xticklabels(bins)
```

The ticks don't match the bins the way I expected; I'd have thought each bar is a 'bin' and so the first bar would be: [0-3], the second: [3-6], etc. Instead each tick spans multiple bars.
(Titanic dataset was being used).

I basically want each bar labelled with the age-range is represents. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of output of above]

Comment: Never only set the labels, without defining their position. I.e. never use `set_xticklabels` without using `set_ticks` as well. Else matplotlib will know which labels to use, but no where to put them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a example (with `.set(xticks=bins)`:

```
bins = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,40,50,60,80]
g = sns.FacetGrid(allData, col="Survived", row="Sex", size=8) 
g = (g.map(plt.hist, "Age", bins=bins)).set(xticks=bins)
```

[image: examples_correct_xticks]

Comment: Thanks, I had thought it would treat each range like a category and have fixed width, but I think this goes back to what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentioned about difference between the ticks and the labels for them.

Answer (score 0):

I never used sns, in matplotlib i have better control over the plot although more typing is required.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fun():
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(100)
    return x


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True, figsize=(14, 8))

binned = list(range(50, 160, 10))

ax[0,0].hist(fun(), binned, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
ax[0,0].set_title('Sex = male | survived = 0')
ax[0,1].hist(fun(), binned, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
ax[0,1].set_title('Sex = male | survived = 1')
ax[1,0].hist(fun(), binned, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
ax[1,0].set_title('Sex = female | survived = 0')
ax[1,1].hist(fun(), binned, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
ax[1,1].set_title('Sex = female | survived = 1')



for col in ax:
    for row in col:
        if row.axes.rowNum == 1:
            row.set_xlabel('age')
        row.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=15)
        row.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        row.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        row.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]